# Flutter Trigger bloc event again

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, state-management, flutter-bloc

On my first screen, I fill out the form and then click the next button it added  `SubmitDataEvent()` to the bloc. Then, the BolcListner listing and when it comes to `SuccessSate` it navigate to the next screen.

on the second screen, when I click the back button it navigates to the previous screen. After that, when I change the user-input data on the form and again click the next button now  `SubmitDataEvent()` is not added.

I preferred some resources related to this and I understand the problem is that the state is in `SuccessSate` and it doesn't change to `InitialState`. So in `dispose()` I used `bloc.close();`

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    bloc.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

But still, it's not working. Also, I try with this code

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    bloc.emit(InitialState);
    bloc.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

still, it's not working.

I used this to navigate between screens:

```
Navigator.popAndPushNamed()
```

**What I want to do is:**
On the first screen, when clicking on the next button  `SubmitDataEvent()` added to the bloc and it in `SuccessState` it navigate to the next screen. When I click the back button on the second page it navigates again to the first screen. Now when I click the next button on the first screen **I want to run all bloc process again.**
*There are no dependencies with the first and second screens.*

first screen code:

```
...
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    bloc = injection<SubmitPersonalDetailsBloc>();

    EasyLoading.addStatusCallback((status) {
      print('EasyLoading Status $status');
      if (status == EasyLoadingStatus.dismiss) {
        _timer?.cancel();
      }
    });
  }

 @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    bloc.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
 @override
  Widget buildView(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocProvider<SubmitPersonalDetailsBloc>(
        create: (_) => bloc,
        child: BlocListener<SubmitPersonalDetailsBloc,
            BaseState<PersonalDetailsState>>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is LoadingSubmitPersonalDetailsState) {
              EasyLoading.show(status: 'Submitting Data');
            }
            if (state is SubmitPersonalDetailsSuccessState) {
              setState(() {
                submitPersonalDetailsResponseEntity =
                    state.submitPersonalDetailsResponseEntity;
              });
              if (submitPersonalDetailsResponseEntity!.responseCode == "00") {
                EasyLoading.showSuccess('Done!');
                //Navigate next screen
                EasyLoading.dismiss();
              }
            } else if (state is SubmitPersonalDetailsFailedState) {
              EasyLoading.showError(state.error);            }
          },
....
```

Comment: Where do you create your bloc?

Comment: Please, Share bloc code snippet.

Comment: I used bloc provider top of the my page

Comment: Try to use Navigator.pushNamed() or Navigator.pushReplacementNamed() for Navigation

Comment: @Poran I added code

Comment: @StefanGaller please check I added code

Comment: @TejaswiniDev can we go, without changing that please

Comment: You need to make sure, your DI library resets the bloc and does not return the same instance. Alternatively, you can add a 'Reset' Event to your bloc and handle it accordingly.

Comment: @StefanGaller how can I do that any example code please

Comment: @AkilaIshan Dispose is called only when state object is removed from the widget tree stack. So its good to use Navigator.pushReplacementNamed or Navigator.pushReplacement(PageB)

Comment: How to send submit event on button next click? show this one

Comment: @Poran now I added please check

Comment: @TejaswiniDev I will try to do that. Thank you

Comment: You added bloc for state management but still calling setState() method.

Comment: @Poran how can I fixed it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on Dependency Injection, Once it creates an instance the parameters don't change. So when navigating to the next screen have to reset that instance.

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    bloc.close();
    injection.resetLazySingleton<SubmitPersonalDetailsBloc>(); // here reset the instance
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this snippet

```
 if (result.responseCode == APIResponse.RESPONSE_SUCCESS) {
                  yield SubmitPersonalDetailsSuccessState(
                      submitPersonalDetailsResponseEntity: r);
                } else
                    yield SubmitPersonalDetailsFailedState(error: r.responseMsg);
                }
```

Comment: still not working